# css best way to set custom css modifications

Tags: css

I have the following styles:

```
.alert {
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
}

.modal .modal-dialog .modal-content {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}
```

This applies for:

```
<div class="modal"></div>
```

I want to have a different style for something like this:

```
<div class="modal alert"></div>
```

But I dont want `.alert` to be applied because that style is for other elements.

I'm doing this:

```
.modal .alert .modal-dialog .modal-content {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  padding: 0px 10px 0 5px;
}
```

But, I get the `.alert` style applied.

> Any clue?

Comment: use `.modal.alert .modal-dialog .modal-content {` - note that there is no space between `modal` and `alert`...

Comment: it should be `.modal.alert` i believe when you call a container with 2 class

Comment: Just update my question, I was missing something.

Comment: As an observation, it would seem you may want to rethink your class / style architecture.  Why are you assigning the class `alert` to the element if you don't want the styles for it? If it's for other purposes (semantic or javascript), then you might consider *not* assigning styles to `alert`, and instead declare a separate class that contains the styles you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `.modal.alert` not to inherit the styles from `.alert` then you should specify it in the .alert style definition:

```
.alert:not(.modal) {
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
}
```

As @cale_b comments it is better to assign a different class name for the `.modal` `.alert` so that you don't have to include the `:not()` selector.

For example:  `<div class="modal modal_alert"></div>`

Comment: This is correct, but in my experience, this can get messy quickly.  I think OP may need to rethink style / class architecture.